# dynamic cell height based on labels

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2

I have just started with IOS development and i am facing issue with `UiTableView`.I want to create an Expandable cell.So after researching i tried but the code works in some phones and not some phones.So i wanted some help.

Storyboard
[image]

At beginning i wanted to show only first 3 labels and then on click i want to show all the labels

Code

```
//to calculate expanded height
    func expandedHeight() -> CGFloat
        {
            let data = arrayDrugs[selectedIndex!.row]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("expandedCell") as! UDCell

            let height = returnLableHeight(cell.lblProducts, fontSize: 16, text: data.packedProd) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblSecondData, fontSize: 15, text: data.dose) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblThirdData, fontSize: 15, text: data.secondData) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblFourthData, fontSize: 15, text: data.thirdData) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblFifthData, fontSize: 15, text: data.fourthData) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblSixthData, fontSize: 15, text: data.fifthData) +
                returnLableHeight(cell.lblSeventhData, fontSize: 15, text: data.sixthData)
            print(height);
            print((cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height)+1)
            cell.sizeToFit()
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return (cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height);

        }

//to calculate collapsed height

        func collapseHeight(indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat{


            let data = arrayDrugs[indexPath.row]

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("expandedCell") as! UDCell

            let height = returnLableHeight(cell.lblProducts, fontSize: 16, text: data.packedProd) +
            returnLableHeight(cell.lblSecondData, fontSize: 15, text: data.dose) +
            returnLableHeight(cell.lblThirdData, fontSize: 15, text: data.secondData)



            //print(height);
           // print((cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingExpandedSize).height)+1)
            cell.sizeToFit()
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()

            return (height+120);

        }

//calculate label height
func returnLableHeight(label:UILabel,fontSize:CGFloat,text:NSAttributedString) -> CGFloat{

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(fontSize)
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.view.frame.width-40;
        label.attributedText = text
//        let rect:CGRect = text.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width-25,CGFloat.max), options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context:nil )//hear u will get nearer height not the exact value
//        let requredSize:CGRect = rect

        label.sizeToFit()

        //print(requredSize.height)
        return label.frame.height
    }
```

Comment: What issues are you facing? Can you be specific?

Comment: height is not being properly created

Comment: This is totally wrong, can you please send me the demo project and I will implement it what you want?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon how can i send you?

Comment: Just upload it to drive or anywhere? @SonaliPawar

Comment: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=764253FA95B1B6F8!30782&authkey=!ABHazEpuHkfZ9Q0&ithint=folder%2c

Comment: @SohilR.Memon der ???

Comment: Yes @SonaliPawar Just give me few minutes

Comment: @SonaliPawar You want to expand in each and every row?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon   yup i wanna do that

Comment: @SonaliPawar You can't manage for all the rows better you can use "Expandable `UITableView`".

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/expandable-table-view/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31591495/expandable-sections-uitableview-indexpath-swift

Comment: https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/ExpandableTableView

Comment: remember to set on table view some estimated row height (most common value).